# How can I easily scroll a product list in flash?

Tags: flash, open-source, image, scroll

Is there a way to have a flash control scroll through a number of images with descriptions without knowing Flash?

Perhaps like LightBox but with nice scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know free ones, but maybe you can look here for a cheap one:

http://www.buystockflash.com/Image-Viewers/Flash-Category30.html

only cost you a couple of dollars and saves you a lot of dev and searchtime ;)

edit:

this one looks nice and free:

http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/